# How can I put spaces in c

Tags: c

I want to put spaces in `printf("%c",player.symbol);`

spaces should be equal to the user input value in the following

```
printf("Next Move [1-%d]: ", game.pathlength);
scanf("%d", &player.location);
```

suppose player.symbol = V and user input Next Move: 8 i.e player.location =8 then the output should be like this:
(8 spaces)V
i.e, there must be 8 spaces before V.

How can I do that?

Comment: you could loop printing spaces or malloc and memset make a string to print

Comment: Please give the exact required output. To left pad with `player.location` number of spaces you can do something like: `printf("%*c", player.location+1, player.symbol);`.

Comment: I gave detailed clarification in the question. hope it helps you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, things to know from the [printf manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> **The field width**
>
> An optional decimal digit string (with nonzero first digit) specifying a minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, it will be padded with spaces on the left ... Instead of a decimal digit string one may write "*" ... to specify that the field width is given in the next argument

With that in mind to achieve the left space padding you require the code would be:

```
printf("%*c", player.location+1, player.symbol);
```

This says that the minimum width of the print is `player.location+1`. Since the `player.symbol` is a single character that means there will be `player.location` of space padding.

Answer (score 0):

You can `printf()` an arbitrary number of spaces by controlling the variable width field character `*` in the following way:

```
void print_spaces(int n)
{
    printf("%*s", n, "");
}
```

So you print an empty string in a field of size the number of spaces you request it to have.